# Customizing the name of an uploaded .zip file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel app accepts user-submitted .zip files, which I temporarily store in local storage:

`Storage::disk('local')->put('exports', $request->custom_report_url);`

The challenge is that this creates a file with what I assume is some kind of hash:

`'app/storage/exports/U44SEhM1wycNgMU0bV6qieSRiGJwMPvkDpBDgkyo.zip'`

This makes that zip file a pain to find later in the process.

Is there a way that I can define a custom name for that zip file? Ideally, I'd like to do something like:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('exports/export_' . $export-id . '.zip', $request->custom_report_url);`
```

However, when I run that code, it creates the following filepath:

`'app/storage/exports/export_1.zip/U44SEhM1wycNgMU0bV6qieSRiGJwMPvkDpBDgkyo.zip'`

Close, but not what I need. Any ideas?

Comment: try like this: *$file =
$request->file('your_input_name')->store('your_path','your_disk')*

Answer (score 0):

I took this from laravel [docs,](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files)

1. You can use `storeAs()` method

   `$path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs(
       'avatars', $request->user()->id
   );`
2. using the `Storage` facade

   ```
   $path = Storage::putFileAs(
       'avatars', $request->file('avatar'), $request->user()->id);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('exports', $request->custom_report_url);
```

I think good process for this is to get the path with a variable. You can rely on laravel hash.

```
$path = Storage::disk('local')->put('exports', $request->custom_report_url);
```

Then save the $path in the database. You can use this path to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code :

**Use File Facade**

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;
```

Make Following Changes in Your Code:

```
$custom_file_name = time().'-'.$request->file('input_field_name')->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $request->file('input_field_name')->storeAs('directory_name',$custom_file_name);
```